# Snubber capacitor vs RC snubber (power supply)

Tags: power-supply, power

I've been looking at various power supply design can across the 2 images below.

- The first design has capacitors across each of the diodes
- The second design has an RC (labelled Rs and Cs) across the AC lines

Can someone please explain the differences and pros/cons of one over the other? (What are the possible problems these two designs are trying to fix?)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Basically, they are placed to remove unwanted oscillations.

The transformer windings have leakage inductances. And these leakage inductances interact with other parasitic elements *(capacitances)* of the entire circuit, and therefore can cause high-frequency oscillations which is also called ringing.

$$
f=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}}
$$

A ringing might create some problems for the rest of the circuit in terms of operation and quality (e.g. EMC). So, sometimes they need to be removed.

It may not be always practical to remove a ringing *completely*. In these cases, there are two options:

1. The frequency of the ringing can be shifted to a less problematic range. A capacitor on its own is enough for that, according to the formula above. But it's not always practical. Because it's possible to end up with a very high capacitance to bring the ringing frequency down to a desired range, and that high capacitance may affect the overall circuit dynamics.
2. The ringing can be damped to some level. This is done with an RC snubber because placing an extra R will turn the parasitic LC tank into an RLC circuit which can have natural damping behaviour as well as lower natural frequency. A damped oscillation shows itself as an oscillation of only a few periods having [gradually decreasing amplitudes](https://d1whtlypfis84e.cloudfront.net/guides/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/26142051/2000px-Damped_sinewave.svg_.png). Damped ringing can be acceptable to some extent thanks to the lesser frequency content and lower amplitudes.

---

**The diode bridge supported with parallel capacitors:** The secondary leakage will oscillate with the diodes' reverse capacitance *(the capacitance seen when the diode is reverse-biased)*. By placing a relatively higher capacitance in parallel, the oscillation frequency can be shifted to a lower, hopefully less problematic range. The better way is to place RC snubbers, of course.

**Snubber across the secondary windings:** This will help the ringing to be damped or even removed completely. In exchange, the losses will increase due to the existence of the resistor.

Comment: is placing a capacitor across each diode equals placing a capacitor parallel the AC lines? Thanks again

Comment: @mrjayviper look at the capacitors (C11 to C14) in the 1st circuit carefully. C11 and C12 are in series, and the combination is in parallel with the secondary. Same for C13 and C14.

Answer (score 4):

Ideal capacitors cannot snub by themselves and rely on the dissipative resistance of the oscillating loop, which is usually very small for switching circuits. If they had more resistance, there wouldn't usually be much to snub in the first place.

Therefore, it is common to add a dissipative element in series with the capacitor: resistors or more rarely/esoterically ferrite beads.